# Xcode 14 stuck at Launching App on Simulator after few runs

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have update my xcode to 14.1 and macOS to Ventura 13.0.1.
When I run my app from xcode on a simulator iPhoneSE 3rd generation (iOS 16) it works fine a few times. After that xcode is unable to launch app on simulator.

The number of time I try to run it keep adding Launching [App Name] to process[image: Build screenshot] .

If I restart simulator it start working again but same thing happens after few runs.I also created new simulator and same thing happens to it as well.

Note: I'm facing same issue for different projects so I think it's not related to my project.

Comment: For me, the hack to the problem is, instead of stopping the build from Xcode, just press the home button in the simulator and kill the app. That way you don't need to re-start the simulator and it saves some time. Yes it is frustrating.

Comment: Finally, Xcode 14.3 works great.

Comment: xcode 14.3, still facing same issue, and there is no Run with Rosetta Stone option. Macbook pro 16" m1 pro, flutter apps runs great, native apps crash every few runs!

Comment: Please find the possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665691/8751294

Comment: @MBH For Xcode 14.3.1 you can go to Product->Destination->Destination Architectures to run on Rosetta.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing this issue on an M2 Macbook Air, every build would open the simulator the first time, but on a second run it would hang on a black screen during "Launching app." It turns out the "fix" was to disable "Open using Rosetta" (Applications > Xcode > Right click > Get Info) which I had turned on because of a third party dependency in a work project that didn't create a proper universal binary, which broke using the simulator on M1.

I think people updating to the new version are installing separately, which has the same effect of disabling the rosetta setting if they were using it already.

Comment: This didn't fix my issue but I think you're pointing in the right direction. My project is using some old dependencies so maybe that's the issue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on M2  with 14.2. I checked the info and "Open using Rosetta" is not selected.

Comment: I don't see this option at Xcode 14.3 to disable Rosetta in Get Info settings

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. Other than this, manually quitting application from simulator instead of stopping from Xcode can also work.

Answer (score 4):

Open Activity Monitor, then search `launch_sim`, kill this process, then I can rerun the sim

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helped me! `sudo killall launchd_sim` to run from Terminal

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded from an old Mac Book Pro 2016 to Mac Book Pro M2 2023 with Xcode 14.3. The first time the simulator would launch the app - and subsequent times I would just see "launching" in Xcode and nothing would happen (I could quite the sim and then it would work). I discovered that removing Build Settings -> Excluded Architectures -> arm64 for my debug and release builds fixes this problem. As noted in comment in Jason's answer, I don't see the option to disable "Open using Rosetta" at Xcode 14.3.

Comment: I need to run on rosetta as i am using a 3rd party library in which i have to exclude arm64 arch. so what to do in this case./

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround not a real fix is to add a run script so it will restart Simulator automatically.

```
if [[ $(uname -m) == 'arm64' ]]; then

pkill Simulator

fi
```

or another way is to just shut down device instead of closing simulator, also should be fine for intel users

```
xcrun simctl shutdown all
```

Script checking if its M1/M2 machine or Intel, because on Intel it doesn't work as fast as M1/M2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case turned out to be that new projects, by default, have parallel testing turned on. But this feature is buggy.

Go to your scheme or test plan and turn parallel testing off!

[image]

Tests will then reliably launch as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. Seems to me that the issue was really in Rosetta. It appeared to me that I used a simulator with Rosetta but there are still options which don't use Rosetta and I switched to one of them and everything started to work just fine.

[image: simulators rosetta]
[image: basic simulators]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually kill these two processes `debugserver` and `lldb-rpc-server`, or create a Pre-actions script for your scheme's Run action to clean up any dangling processes before Xcode runs your app.

```
pkill debugserver
pkill lldb-rpc-server
```

[image]

I accidentally discovered this when my debugging process hogged the CPU for 99%, and the only way to kill it is by killing its parent process `debugserver` and `lldb-rpc-server`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to edit the scheme and check the box "Launch app without state restoration"[image]

Answer (score -3):

I was facing this issue by way of temporary solution likes

1. a scheme's "Build Pre-actions"
2. killall "Simulator" || true